# Cumulative Total Downloads in Google Play Developer Console 2021

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

On the Google Play Store I have always used the number of total cumulative installs as part of my growth plan.

However, I am no longer able to see "cumulative total installs". Show only "Active Installations".

It seems that Google has changed the organization again, so much so that the answers of 2019/2020 are not useful.

How can I see them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to get cumulative total download on Google Play Console, I had to:

1. Search for “Statistics” tab
2. Change the report configuration a bit. First, click “Installed
   audience” (the default metric), and navigate the menu as following:

   **Users > User Acquisitions > New Users**
3. Click the “Edit” button And change the “Events” to “Unique Users“. This ensures that the final report will not be over-counted if you’ve had a significant number of users who have uninstalled and re-installed your app over time.
4. Also adjust the metric calculation to “Cumulative“. This means each
   data point along your time series will be equal to your total
   installs accumulated up until that day.

Answer (score 1):

On your main dashboard, set your time range to "Lifetime". Then you will see the total installs in the "New users acquired" section

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot see the cumulative downloads. I can only see daily installs.

Comment: You will see all the installs of all the days added up and therefore will have the "Total Downloads" as you asked in the question.

Comment: I meant "cumulative total installs". I've edited the question (it was quite confusing, you're right)